# How to call method inside the VB.NET Module

Tags: vb.net

I have the following VB.NET code:

```
Namespace Data 
    Public Module Part
        Public function IsValidPart() 
        End Function
    End Module
End NameSpace
```

Now, how do I call the `IsValidPart` method in the `Part` module?  When I try to call the method, I get the following error:

> The type initializer for 'MyCompany.Lender.Data.Part' threw an
>   exception. --->  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem code is not in your snippet.  It is caused by an initialization of a variable in your module.  A simple example of such a problem is:

```
Module Module1
    Public Example As String = Nothing.ToString()

    Sub Main()
    End Sub
End Module
```

You get a non-descript TypeInitializationException when the static constructor for the module runs.  Which is code that the compiler generates to ensure the *Example* variable gets initialized.  Unfortunately, the debugger doesn't display a good diagnostic for this.

You can find the problem statement with Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown box for CLR exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Like you would call a Static/Shared Method:

```
Part.IsValidPart()
```

All members in a Module are shared / static.

> I get the following error: The type initializer for 'MyCompany.Lender.Data.Part'

**EDIT**:

You have a `Sub New` in your module that is throwing a Null Reference Exception:

```
Sub New()
    'An exception is being thrown somewhere in here
End Sub
```

Fix your exception, you can get more detail if you run with a debugger attached.

Comment: Please see the updated question for the error message. I call the method exactly as you have implemented.

Comment: I have checked the file and there is no New Sub. Still it throws the nullReferenceException.

Comment: @azamsharp Then you have a field initializer throwing an exception. Han's answer explains this.